# Equals method inheritance confusion

Tags: c#, inheritance

Say I have one class, `ClassB`, that extends another class, `ClassA`, by adding another property not in `ClassA`. Would the following equals method work?

```
public bool Equals(ClassB other)
{
    return this.ExtraProp == other.ExtraProp && base.Equals(ClassB);
}
```

Why should I be allowed to pass a `ClassB` object to the equals method of `ClassA` (only takes `ClassA` objects)? Is this just how inheritance works?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a `ClassB` object *is* a `ClassA` object.  You can always, anywhere, treat a `ClassB` object as if it were a `ClassA` object.  This is the essence of polymorphism.

As for whether it would actually return the proper result, that is going to depend on your implementation of `ClassA`.  Certain implementation wouldn't work as this code is expecting them to, but other implementations would.

Let's use a concrete example here.  Let's say that this is the definition of `ClassA`:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int first;
    public int second;
    public bool Equals(ClassA other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        return first == other.first &&
            second == other.second;
    }
}
```

Now let's say we have these objects:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA() { first = 1, second = 2 };
ClassB b = new ClassB() { first = 1, second = 2, third = 3 };
```

Here `a.Equals(b)` will be `true`.  It has both of the properties that are checked for, so it considers them equal.  Do you *want* these objects to be considered equal?

Another implementation would be to do this:

```
public bool Equals(ClassA other)
{
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other.GetType() != typeof(ClassA)) return false;
    return first == other.first &&
        second == other.second;
}
```

Here we're explicitly checking (granted, at runtime, not at compile time) to be sure that the other instance isn't of a more derived type.  In this case `a.Equals(b)` would be false.  You can implement whichever semantics you prefer.

Comment: +1 for polymorphism.  This is also Liskov Substitution Principle in action =)

Comment: +1. Good explanation. But you have to be careful here. If you override `ClassB.Equals<ClassB>`, then you can get in the situation where you have `A.Equals(B) == true` and `B.Equals(A) == false`. It can be very confusing. As you say, it depends on the semantics you prefer. I've been burned often enough that I prefer your second implementation: two objects aren't equal unless they're the identical type. If I need inherited types to compare as equal, I'll create a custom equality comparer.

Answer (score 1):

`Employee` inherits from `Human`.

`Employee` has more properties than just a `Human`, but it is still a `Human`.

If you implement a `Human.Equals()`  you can pass in an `Employee` because deepdown at heart `Employees` are still `Humans`.... but you cannot treat `Humans` like `Employees`, because not all `Humans` have the `Earnings` Property